# REST API - Recipient View - How to configure multiple returnUrl's per Event

Tags: docusignapi

I'm attempting to build embedded signing with my integration via REST API. I can successfully create the token with the bare minimum requirements.

{
    "userName": "Derrick Test",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "recipientId": "1",
    "clientUserId": "1",
    "returnUrl": "http://www.google.com",
    "authenticationMethod": "email"
}

What I would like to enhance is redirect my signers to a specific URL on more than just completion. More specifically I would like to configure a different URL for the events:

> cancel
>   decline
>   signing_complete
>   viewing_complete

The REST documentation does not provide a JSON example when utilizing multiple events. Has anyone else been successful with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the REST API, you can only supply a single **returnUrl**, and it will apply for any/all events (i.e., cancel / decline / exception / fax_pending / id_check_failed / session_timeout / signing_complete / ttl_expired / viewing_complete).  However, you can achieve the effect of having the user's destination be event-dependent simply by coding your return page to evaluate the **event** parameter in the querystring, and doing another redirect immediately to the event-specific page, depending on the value of the **event** querystring parameter.

For example, let's say you specify **http://www.myfakesite.com/processReturn.aspx** as the **returnUrl** value in the *POST Recipient View* request.  When the recipient signs the document(s) and submits the Envelope, DocuSign will redirect the user to the URL:  **http://www.myfakesite.com/processReturn.aspx?event=signing_complete**.  Assuming you've built "processReturn.aspx" such that it evaluates the value of the **event** querystring parameter, it will see value "**signing_complete**" and then immediately redirect to the appropriate page (that you specify in the code) for the Signing Complete event.

Page 167 (**returnUrl** property description) of the REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) lists all possible values for the **event** parameter.